# Vertical Align Text Under Image in Div Box?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I have rows of product thumbnails with the product text below. See [here](http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/banquettes/designer-banquettes/)

Since the images have different heights the text is not always vertically aligned in the right place. I just changed the layout from tables to divs because it's easier and more modern.

I've worked through several examples, websites, and this site but still haven't found a way to align this correctly. I'd like the image aligned in the middle of the div and the text at the very bottom.

Here's the DIV code (very simple):

```
<div style="float:left; width:210px; height:200px; text-align:center;" >
    <a title="Alton Banquette" href="http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/banquettes/designer-banquettes/alton-banquette/"><img  alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ALTON-SETTEE_THUMB.gif" width="150" height="150" border="0" /></a>
Alton Banquette
</div>
```

It works fine on [this page](http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/ottomans/) since the images are all the same height

Is there a simple solution to this? I like DIVS better but this wasn't a problem when everything was table cells since I could use `valign=center`, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Always assign a class and organize your code , always wrap your text to avoid glitches:

```
<div class="wrap" >  

<a title="Alton Banquette" href="http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/banquettes/designer-banquettes/alton-banquette/">
    <img  alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ALTON-SETTEE_THUMB.gif" width="150" height="150" border="0" />
</a>
<p>Alton Banquette</p>   

</div>
.wrap
{
    float:left; width:210px; height:200px; text-align:center;
}
}
.wrap p
{

  display:block;

}
img
{
    height:100% !important;
    width:auto;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/6yag9/6/)

so whenever you change the image height , text will always remain at bottom.

Comment: Hi ProllyGeek,

This doesn't seem to be working for me. The text is already under the images in the div. The issue is since the images have varying heights ... the text isn't always at the bottom of the div. 

I'd like the image to be centered vertically in the div and have the  text at the very bottom (much like product thumbnails would look).

Thanks for a start on this though!

Comment: my solution will keep the text always at very bottom , but from what i see your problem is you have varying heights images , and you want to keep all the same height within the wrapper div , correct ?

Comment: Basically I want the wrapper divs the same size and regardless of image size the text to remain on the very bottom. I used to just use two <tr> rows to handle this.

Comment: then you have to handle the image itself , not the wrapper div , so that whenever images resize they keep same height inside the wrapper div , i edited my naswer , hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: ProllyGeek it doesn't seem to be working. It blows out the images to be too large. I'm basically trying to have a row of images with a row of image names below all aligned equally independent of the image heights (which are specified via HTML).

Comment: just give me some images examples , and let me send a full solution , obviously i dont get you at all.

Comment: ProllyGeek,

Here's the page. Now I'm messing with giving a set image height but the width/image scale is getting messed up using max-width/min-width, etc.

http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/banquettes/designer-banquettes/

Here's an example page that looks great BC all the images already have the same size height.

http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/ottomans/

Comment: so you want all images beside each other in one row ? disregarding their widths ?

Comment: I'd prefer the widths fit the DIV and the heights be the same or smaller if need be to fit the width.

Comment: If I can't do this as one div and need to have multiple divs or something please let me know. Maybe I'm being foolish.